# I can only see the first website alphabetically

Tags: apache-2.2, ubuntu, bind

I have 3 subdomains websites. Those are subdomain1.mydomain.com, subdomain2.mydomain.com, subdomain3.mydomain.com. 
I have point these to the external IP address.
bind is ok, dig is onerror, Apache2 reload ok

1.) If I set the following, I can only see the first one alphabetically.

```
NameVirtualHost *:80    
<VirtualHost *:80>    
   ServerName subdomain1.mydomain.com
...    
<VirtualHost *:80>    
   ServerName subdomain2.mydomain.com
...
```

2.) If I set the following, I get file not found. Apache2 reload ok.

```
NameVirtualHost mydomain.com:80    
<VirtualHost mydomain.com:80>    
   ServerName subdomain1.mydomain.com
...
<VirtualHost mydomain.com:80>    
   ServerName subdomain2.mydomain.com
```

Please Help! What else should I do.

Comment: What do you mean by "see" the website?

Comment: Please provide the output from `apachectl -S`

Comment: I mean I browse it from outside the network with another IP address.

Comment: apachectl -S  apachectl: command not found

Comment: apache2ctl -S
IP:80 is a NameVirtualHost  // I have NameVirtualHost mydomain.com here, why it become IP
port 80 namevhost subdomains.mydomain.com(/etc/apache2/sites-enable/subdomain1.mydomain.com:56)   // what is the last number stand for ??

Answer (score 0):

you should have following:

```
NameVirtualHost IP:80

<VirtualHost IP:80>
  ServerName subdomain1.mydomain.com
  ...
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost IP:80>
  ServerName subdomain2.mydomain.com
  ...
</VirtualHost>
```

*** UPDATE ***

[Name-based Virtual Host Support - Apache HTTP Server](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/vhosts/name-based.html)

Comment: I want to use name base

Comment: what I provided _IS_ a name based virtualhost, look at URL to read more how to configure it properly

Comment: after you configure it use `httpd -S` to see how apache sees your configiuration

Answer (score 0):

See http://wiki.apache.org/httpd/CommonMisconfigurations

Your first code sample is correct. You should use wildcards, e.g. `NameVirtualHost *:80` and `<VirtualHost *:80>`, otherwise you can not reliably test it from the same machine.

From your comment:

> I mean I browse it from outside the network with another IP address.

You must test it using the DNS name (or a hosts file entry, or defining the HOST header)

Comment: If you have registered a domain name: `curl http://domainname/`. If you haven't registered a domain name: `curl -H "Host: domainname" http://ipaddr/"

Comment: Hi, Fuzzyfelt. I have try curl http://subdomain1.mydomain.com/ which come up the home page with noframes in ubuntu. But for curl http://subdomain2.mydomain.com/ there no reaction. Why? and what does it means?

Comment: @Victor Please update your question with details about how you've registered subdomain2.mydomain.com to your IP address, the result from `dig subdomain2.mydomain.com`, where you're testing from and the exact output from curl.